# How do I scout with a bat familiar?

Tags: dnd-4e, familiars

My gaming group in a few encounters will be hitting level 14. I plan on taking the arcane familiar feat, and choosing the bat familiar.  My plan is to have the bat passive inside my cloak to gain the benefits of its blindsight while scouting around for my party.  Assuming I myself am hidden, would I still need to roll for the bat using my modifiers? And would I have to have the bat on my shoulder for its blindsight to even work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Exactly what your familiar does while in passive mode is unspecified, and entirely fluff. (*Arcane Power* says "perching on your shoulder or hiding in your pocket," but those are just examples. Later in the same chapter, it also says "you can also determine what happens when your familiar enters passive mode.") Mechanically, a passive familiar is little different from a worn magic item, and you don't have to make a separate stealth check for your armor or your gauntlets, do you?

Conceptually, if you've got a little bat on your shoulder, there's not much reason why *that* would give you away when you're already sneaking around. (On the other hand, if you fail your skill check, you could fluff it that your bat made some noise or flapped his wings and the guards noticed the movement/sound.)